Multiple sequential tasks per node with slurm batch script
I'm performing a finite element analysis using a software called ElmerFEM. The input to the simulation, a mesh file, is partitioned into 40 segments. Each segment can be distributed to a node for concurrent analysis. My issue is that I don't have access to 40 nodes. To my understanding with slurm, if you allocate more than 1 task per node, each node will run these tasks concurrently. Normally this would be fine but my nodes don't have enough memory for this to be acceptable. I need each node to only run one of these tasks at a time.
Lets say I have split up the input mesh into 40 partitions (therefore, 40 slurm tasks are needed). Lets also say I only have access to 5 nodes (each node only having four physical cores). Would it be possible for me to allocate 8 tasks to each of these nodes (8*5 = 40) and have each node only run one task at a time? I know this is inefficient but it is the only solution available for my workload.
I have the following sbatch script. Currently, if I run it I get an error about not having an available configuration for the given requirements (slurm is looking for nodes that have 8 cores and my compute cluster does not have any nodes like that).
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=elm_x
#SBATCH --output=log/%x-%A_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=log/%x-%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --nodes=5
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=40
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8

srun --mpi=pmix /usr/bin/ElmerSolver_mpi case.sif


Your question is not clear. Anyway, what about allocating one task per node but in exclusive mode?

@GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the feedback and suggestion. I'll give your suggestion and try and also make some clarifications to the post.

@GillesGouaillardet I have updated the question, hopefully it is more clear now.
I thought the exclusive flag meant that different jobs can't use the same node. Are you saying it means that different tasks from the same job can't use the same node?
I gave your suggestion a try by setting #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1 and adding #SBATCH --exclusive to the script I gave in my question. Unfortunately, slurm is saying sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available

MPI jobs must run all the tasks in parallel. Also, the default configuration is SLURM won't let you allocate more cores than available, so if a node only has 4 physical cores, you cannot allocate 8 tasks per node.

Darn that's news I wasn't wanting to hear :(
I'll see if I can make a different plan then. Thanks so much for your help!

This question is more related to the software you use than to SLURM. The answer is in your hands. Can you run your software sequentially? I mean: using your own computer, with no SLURM, assuming one node, one CPU and as much memory as required, could you run the 40 segments sequentially and independently? If yes, then you can do that using SLURM. If not, then you cannot do that using SLURM either.
